# maildev page at http://0.0.0.0:1080 might be temporarily down?

Tags: spring-boot, email, web, email-validation

I am trying out maildev for sending emails project on a spring boot project. I have successfully installed maildev and I am able to start the mail server successfully as shown below[
When i serch http://0.0.0.0:1080 in the browser i get "...It looks like the webpage at http://0.0.0.0:1080/ might be having issues or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."
[image: erro page]

I have tried out clearing browser cache, changed browser security setting to allow unprotected sources, tried both explorer and chrome browser and also tried out this solution for this erro as surgested by microsoft but it didnt work.[image: working page]
i expect the default devmail server page which displays as follows and iam wondering what might be the problem.

Comment: The solution suggested by Microsoft is found here  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/microsoft-edge-error/ca6bb135-71ae-467d-92dc-3303236360ae

Answer (score 0):

> Configure your application to send emails via port 1025 and open localhost:1080 in your browser.

https://github.com/maildev/maildev#configure-your-project

If http://localhost:1080 doesn‘t work, try http://127.0.0.1:1080

Comment: both solutions work thanks, Chris.  That IP address (http://0.0.0.0:/) is the problem

Comment: Correct. 0.0.0.0 is valid for services *listening* to *any* IP address on their host, but invalid for calling a service.